# Set image in Picture-box from Business Logic Class to Main application Class

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, wikipedia-api

I write a c# code according to software architecture. In business logic layer I implement a code by which I can extract data from wikipedia api to get image. I want to show it on application layer which is `Form1.cs`. But it is not working at all. My code for getting the image from Wikipedia looks like this:

```
public class ImageService
{
    private string _baseUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=400&titles={0}";

    public string GetImage(string name)
    {
        string requestUrl = string.Format(_baseUrl, name);
        string result;

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {    
            var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri(_baseUrl));
            var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImgRootobject>(response);
            var firstKey = responseJson.query.pages.First().Key;
            result = responseJson.query.pages[firstKey].thumbnail.source;
            string Image_title = responseJson.query.pages[firstKey].title;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

My `Form1.cs` is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly ImageService _imageService;
    public Form1()
    {

        _imageService = new ImageService();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.LoadAsync(_imageService);

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to expand on "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call the `GetImage` method from `ImageService` which returns the string. The [`LoadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww2xzydc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the `PictureBox` accept one *string* as it's parameter but you've sent an instance of `ImageService` to it. It should be like this:

```
pictureBox1.LoadAsync(_imageService.GetImage(a string parameter for name));
```

Comment: I think, you should try "pictureBox1.LoadAsync(_imageService.GetImage("your image name parameter"));"